# Dangers of meganeura sized dragonflie for child sized humanoids

Tags: creature-design, insects

Would a dragonfly around the size of a [Meganeura](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meganeura) be a concrete danger for a humanoid about a meter (3'3") tall, weighing around 15kg (33lb)?

This dragonfly wouldn't have particular evolutionary adaptations to be able to predate large animals, being basically just scaled up to have a wingspan of approximately 70cm (27").

The humanoids, on the other hand, are somewhat frail, possessing long and thin bones.
They don't have massive anatomical differences from humans, except for some differences in the respiratory system, being closer to a bird's, and, obviously, their stature.

My question is whether or not this insect would be considerably dangerous and perhaps kill or severely hurt these humanoids.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to make yourself familiar with our standards. Your question lacks some details: By size alone is hard to tell if something is dangerous or not.

Comment: Assuming wingspan is 1.5x body length, a 69 cm wingspan equates to a body 46 cm or 1.5' long. A 1.5' carnivore would believably target 3.3' prey, or more likely, the children

Comment: @nzaman: While I don't know about Meganeura, modern dragonflies typically use superior speed & maneuverability to catch smaller airborne prey in a "basket" formed by their legs: https://www.dragonfly-site.com/what-do-dragonflies-eat.html  So unless the humanoid can fly, no.  But the immature nymphs might be a real danger to swimmers.

Comment: @jamesqf Thank you for the nymphs input, but i think I will have to abandon the idea of dragonflies altogether. A more pressing reason (related to the culture of these humanoids) basically forces me to have a seawater enviroment, and insects eggs and nymphs can't develop with such high salinity levels.

Comment: A toddler would likely be about 15 inches tall and 2.5 lb, so yeah.